Issue with with pgadmin Format SQL
I was experiencing issues with pgAdmin when formatting my queries using (Cmd+Shift+K). After updating to the latest version of pgAdmin, I continue to face formatting problems using (Ctrl+Shift+K), where my query becomes jumbled. Any thoughts? Also, could you recommend any tools other than pgAdmin and PostgreSQL?

Issue worked-around using DBBeaver
